# Detect Flexbox Responsiveness to remove snappiness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I was wondering if there is a way to detect flexbox responsive after a window is shrunk, and a certain class is moved under. What happens currently is that the overflowing box will disappear suddenly and appear under in an instant (which creates a snap effect). What I want to achieve is to detect the disappearing box so that it appears under/next to each other with an easing effect(not just snap into place).
Here is a sample code:

```css
body{
  background-color:grey;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out, transform .2s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #4aa8ea;
}

.zoom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s, filter 2s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box:hover .zoom {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.centerImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ttl {
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:20px;
}

.desc {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:white;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
  column-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Animal Collection</h1>
    <p>Get a look at all the species!</p>

    <div class="outer">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://www.owlsecurity.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/buho.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">OWL</div>
        <div class="desc">
          <div class="wrapper"> The owl is a very fascinating species that is nocturnal. It is considered as a predator</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/70/a1/58/70a1580630e2233978c0755f7215a3a2.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">CAT</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The cat or feline is a descendant of a lion. It can jump as high as 13 feet </div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    


  </body>

</html>
```

and a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s479vovz/134/)

In this case, the toucan will disappear and appear in an instant and thus, the snappy effect. Can the toucan ease out after moving under?